# Chrome Console returning 8 Nan from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following function

```
function QuantityCheckout () {
  var obj = {
    "BackGlassQty": Cookies.get('BackGlassQty'),
    "BackCameraQty": Cookies.get('BackCameraQty'),
    "BatteryQty": Cookies.get('BatteryQty'),
    "ChargingPortQty": Cookies.get('ChargingPortQty'),
    "FrontCameraQty": Cookies.get('FrontCameraQty'),
    "GlassCameraCoverQty": Cookies.get('GlassCameraCoverQty'),
    "LogicBoardQty": Cookies.get('LogicBoardQty'),
    "ScreenQty": Cookies.get('ScreenQty')
  };
  $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    var test = '#' + key - 'qty' + 'Quantity'
    console.log(test);
    $('#' + key - 'qty' + 'Quantity').text('Quantity:' + value);
  });
}
```

and it keeps returning 8 in a circle and NaNQuantity.

Comment: you should use `var test = '#' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity'` if you want to take out the 'Qty' from the name

Comment: no problem, was this the solution? in that case i'll create a answer in order to close this question

Comment: Yes it was @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: Excellent, set the answer as right in order to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `-` operator for String in Js. Instead you should use the `replace` function, and so your code should become:

```
var test = '#' + key.replace('Qty', '') + 'Quantity'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you join the string you have a minus in there so it is trying to do a mathematical calculation instead, which is why you get `NaN`.

Use a `+` to concatenate the strings.

```js
const Cookies = {
  get: () => {}
}

function QuantityCheckout () {
  var obj = {
    "BackGlassQty": Cookies.get('BackGlassQty'),
    "BackCameraQty": Cookies.get('BackCameraQty'),
    "BatteryQty": Cookies.get('BatteryQty'),
    "ChargingPortQty": Cookies.get('ChargingPortQty'),
    "FrontCameraQty": Cookies.get('FrontCameraQty'),
    "GlassCameraCoverQty": Cookies.get('GlassCameraCoverQty'),
    "LogicBoardQty": Cookies.get('LogicBoardQty'),
    "ScreenQty": Cookies.get('ScreenQty')
  };
  $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    var test = '#' + key + 'qty' + 'Quantity'
    console.log(test);
    $('#' + key + 'qty' + 'Quantity').text('Quantity:' + value);
  });
}

QuantityCheckout()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can use back ticks

```
var test = `#${key}qtyQuantity`
```